# Self-sustained vs. non-self-sustained discharge systems

Tags: electricity, experimental-technique

I don't quite understand what a self-sustained discharge is. I figure it means that the processes involved are self supporting and generate themselves, so that I don't have to put energy into the system and generate an outside voltage at the electrodes. Can an experimental device ever by fully self-sustained? If yes, wouldn't that mean I can't control when it's running or now?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're talking about electrical discharge in gases, or something similar.

In a self sustained discharge the potential gradient is sufficiently high that free electrons are accelerated hard enough to ionise atoms they collide with. This means that as the current flows it keeps a population of ions and free electrons present. In this type of system, once you have got a current flowing the current continues to flow.

However if the potential gradient is too low, free electrons cannot ionise other atoms, and the population of ions and free electrons is radidly depleted. You need some external influence to ionise the gas in order to get current to flow. This is a non self sustained discharge.

The Wikipedia article on [electric discharge in gases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_discharge_in_gases) has more on this, or Google for many related articles such as [this one](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Electric+Discharge+in+Gases).

Comment: So you're saying a non-self-sustainded discharge needs more than the gas flow and the voltage? Like laser induced ionization from time to time? But in any case both need you to apply a voltage, right?

Comment: Yes. And now I need 11 more characters before I can post this comment.

Comment: Take these: Hamlet, Hermione, Michelangelo (Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles a.k.a. Teenage Mutant Hero Turtles), Speedy Gonzales, Dr. Peter Venkman (Ghostbusters), Peter Parker, Marty McFly, Gohan, Columbo, Blair Waldof (Gossip Girl), Ted "Theodore" Logan (Bill and Teds excellent adventure).

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple example for non-self- sustained discharge phenomenon. It is known that the friction charged insulator conductors lose their charge. The reason for the event is non-self- sustained discharge. Roughly, the ions and electrons cannot stimulate each other and so recombine to become neutral. However, old times, people thought that charge leaks through air.